# Generics - Passing instances as a base type

Tags: c#, templates, generics

I'm currently working on the Data Access Layer for our new application, it's not a large application so I've decided to go with a Dao pattern, converting each Model item into a Dao Item before storing it to the database through stored queries.

With as much as possible of this I've used generic interfaces and abstract classes to remove the repetitive operations but now I've hit a bit of a road block.
What we have is an Interface for Dao Conversion classes looking like the following:

```
internal interface IDaoConverter<TModel, TDao>
    where TModel : ModelItem
    where TDao : DaoItem
{
    ToDao(TModel inModel);
    inDao);
}
```

This works fine so far and fits it's function, you specify the Model type and the Dao type it will be converted into (1-1 relationship) in the class definition and the functions are created to match these types. Instances of these Dao Converters are held in a factory to make the retrieval easier.

The next thing I want is to create Data Access classes that will use this and I want to design this in a Generic way.

What I'm after is a way to ask the Dao Converter Factory that I want a Dao Converter that can handle a specific type of Model item but so far I can't find a way to specify this.

```
public abstract class AbstractDataAccess<T> where T: ModelItem
{
    protected IDaoConverter<T,?> Converter;

    public void Init(IDaoConverter<T,?> inConverter)
    {
        Converter = inConverter;
    }
}
```

I basically want to be able to replace the Question Marks with whatever type I want within the class. I'm currently having to write each Data Access class out completely due to this.

Comment: Why don't use AutoMapper?

Comment: You are using generics on your interface, but... if you are explicitly telling that a `TDao` is a `DaoItem` class, why not declare it as `internal interface IDaoConverter<TModel>` with methods like `DaoItem ToDao(TModel inModel)`?

Comment: AutoMapper is a great choice for this situation to reduce the boilerplate for converting from Model to DAO or DTO

Comment: @HuorSwords My aim was to stick to strongly typed parameters,  I looked at just specifying them as the DaoItem type but then the Database functions which take a specifc type of DaoItem also need to lose their strong typing.

Comment: @Peyman We've never really looked at AutoMapper but I'll try and find some time. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the converter is given at initialization, you could make the methods accessing the DaoConverter abstract, and derive a (possibly abstract) class that has a second type parameter representing the Dao-Type.

```
public abstract class AbstractDataAccess<T, TDao> : AbstractDataAccess<T> where ...
```